# Python Recursion: Range

Tags: python, recursion, range

I need to define a function called rec_range(n) which takes a natural number and returns a TUPLE of numbers up to the number n.

i.e. rec_range(5) returns (0,1,2,3,4) 
     rec_range(1) returns (0,)

This is what I have come up with so far.

```
def rec_range(n):
    """takes a natural number n and returns a tuple of numbers starting with 0     and ending before n

    Natural Number -> Tuple of Numbers"""
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (rec_range(n-1), )
```

This works for rec_range(1).

***Restrictions are: must be defined recursively, cannot use lists, loops or use the existing range() function

Comment: Once you get this working, try `rec_range(1500)` and you'll discover why recursion isn't the magical solution to all problems ;-)

Comment: @Kevin: That just exposes a problem with languages that lack tail-call optimization and have a limit for how large their stack is allowed to grow.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare this recursion is not even a tail recursion...

Comment: @Kevin: Also, even if you would do it with tail recursion and could have TCO in Python, it'd still be O(n^2) because of the concatenation inherent in the system ... er, I mean because tuples are implemented using flat, immutable arrays, so you have to copy all the items whenever you concatenate them

Comment: You might want to suggest your teacher to use a different programming language for such exercises, like a Lisp, Haskell, ML  ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write it as follows:

```
def rec_range(n):
    if n < 1:
        return ()
    else:
        return rec_range(n - 1) + (n - 1,)

print(rec_range(4)) # prints (0, 1, 2, 3)
```

This can also handle negative arguments.

Comment: @Trumpetplayer0098: in that case, you should accept this answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is nice and concise, I think:

```
def rec_range(n):
    if not n <= 1: return rec_range(n-1) + (n-1,)
    return (0,)
```

Basically you recurse downwards until you reach 1, and for each recursion add one less than the number that you just recursed on position wise to your tuple.

**Outputs:**

```
>>>rec_range(4)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `rec_range(0)` => BOOM

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare :P but he specifies that this function is supposed to consume a natural number.

Comment: Eh, it's trivial to modify the program to not explode with non-natural numbers (just change `n == 1` to `n <= 1`) so I would do it. Using your solution crashes with any float or any value under 1. That one change fixes both of those.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in my answer below a few minutes ago.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Sorry, what?

Comment: I used a greater than to test my recursion level rather than testing for one.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Edited just for you :)

Comment: @MalikBrahimi And...nice approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep concatenating tuples for the number that is one less until one is reached:

```
rec_range = lambda n: rec_range(n - 1) + (n - 1,) if n > 0 else ()
```

Comment: Why passing lists to `tuple()` instead of just using tuple literals? `tuple([n - 1])` is the same as `(n-1,)`.

Comment: Assigning lambdas is considered [bad style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: @mata: The OP is asking for an inefficient, broken (for n > 1000 or so), reimplementation of something that's already available as a builtin.  I think a minor PEP8 violation is fairly insignificant in comparison. :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is simple one:

```
def getrange(a,b,c=1): 
     if a < b: 
        print(a)
        a+=c  
        getrange(a,b,c)
    else:
        return

getrange(0,30,2)
```

Answer (score -1):

How about a one-liner:

```
def rec_range(n):
    return rec_range(n-1) + (n-1,) if n > 0 else ()
```

Or with lambdas:

```
rec_range = lambda n: rec_range(n-1) + (n-1,) if n > 0 else ()
```

Comment: Yeah, the range should be exclusive. That's all.

Comment: Also, try returning an empty tuple for bad input values. That way when iterating the code block wont execute just as if you were using a traditional range.

Comment: `rec_range(5)` -> `(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`?